# Web api: Getting 403 Forbidden for different string parameter content

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, http-status-code-403

In my project I do not have access to the dev and test database and so it becomes very hard to debug sometimes.

So I added an api to fetch data from the database by passing the sql query in the post body for the debugging purposes from swagger.

The api looks like this

```
 [HttpPost("fetch-database")]
 [Produces(MediaTypeNames.Application.Json)]
 [Authorize(Roles = ClaimRoles.Admin)]
 public async Task<ContentResult> FetchDatabase(string query)
 {
     var result = await masterlookup.FetchDatabaseAsync(query);

     return Content(result, "application/json");
 }
```

The very very strange  thing that is happening is that it works for some queries while return `403 Forbidden` for some queries.

So if I pass this query, it works

```
select * from Table t
```

But if I add order by clause to the query like this

```
 select * from Table t order by t.d desc
```

or if I select specific columns like this

```
select t.id, t.name from Table t
```

It fails with a forbidden message

```
<html>
<head><title>403 Forbidden</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>403 Forbidden</h1></center>
<hr><center>Microsoft-Azure-Application-Gateway/v2</center>
</body>
</html>
```

This is really strange because it should not matter what is the content of the string that I am passing.

Any idea what could be going wrong?

Comment: [Please try this sample code](https://codeshare.io/nz1zpM), I mean hard code the query in your method, and don't pass the params in the api, to check the result.  This can be ruled out as being related to the security mechanism of Azure Gateway.

Comment: @JasonPan - The query was working fine when it is hardcoded. I have solved it by reading the parameter from the body. I posted the answer, you can have a look. Thanks anyways for helping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved it by making the query parameter being read by request body using `FromBody` attribute.

So even when the method type was post it was still sending the parameter `query` in query string. So now forcing the parameter to be read from the request body.

Looks like something was not being allowed when the whole query was going through query string.

So basically I changed the signature of the method like this

```
public async Task<ContentResult> FetchDatabase([FromBody]string query)
```